# How to hide/show CustomInfoWindow at map in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart

I am in flutter developer. i want to simple map application. where have some feature. one of them when i click on marker then show my custom window again click on marker then hide custom window.

at this moment. only show custom window but not hide custom window when click on marker.

my source code details in below:

```
import 'package:clippy_flutter/triangle.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

import 'package:custom_info_window/custom_info_window.dart';

class CustomInfoWindowF extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomInfoWindowExampleState createState() =>
      _CustomInfoWindowExampleState();
}

class _CustomInfoWindowExampleState extends State<CustomInfoWindowF> {
  CustomInfoWindowController _customInfoWindowController =
  CustomInfoWindowController();

  final LatLng _latLng = LatLng(28.7041, 77.1025);
  final double _zoom = 15.0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _customInfoWindowController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Set<Marker> _markers = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId("marker_id"),
        position: _latLng,
        onTap: () {
          _customInfoWindowController.addInfoWindow(
            Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.account_circle,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 8.0,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "I am here",
                                style:
                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: double.infinity,
                  ),
                ),
                Triangle.isosceles(
                  edge: Edge.BOTTOM,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            _latLng,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Info Window Example'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          GoogleMap(
            onTap: (position) {
              _customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow();
            },
            onCameraMove: (position) {
              _customInfoWindowController.onCameraMove();
            },
            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
              _customInfoWindowController.googleMapController = controller;
            },
            markers: _markers,
            initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
              target: _latLng,
              zoom: _zoom,
            ),
          ),
          CustomInfoWindow(
            controller: _customInfoWindowController,
            height: 175,
            width: 250,
            offset: 50,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my pubspec.yaml dependencies file source code below

```
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  custom_info_window: ^1.0.1
  clippy_flutter: ^1.1.1
```

Comment: it was critical for me. but i have solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create one button in my CustomInfoWindow then onPress
call

```
_customInfoWindowController.hideInfoWindow();
```

it will be solved. thanks